# what is the use of making a string static

Tags: java, string

If I am not wrong, how many ever same Strings are created, only in only place it is stored by using String interning. If so, what is the use of making a Sting static if it is already being stored in only one place in memory which is nothing but acting as if it was a static variable. Thanks.

Comment: You have to start making the distinction between objects and variables. `static` applies to variables, not to objects.

Comment: Can you actually show the context code you're referring to? In Java, usually you declare a variable `static` if you want it to be a *class variable* as opposed to an *instance variable*.

Comment: it should allow the compiler to optimize the way that string is stored and (not) edited.

Comment: Also, strings are only interned if they're compile-time constants or you call intern explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static Strings can be accessed outside the class without creating the class's variable. Example of this is:

```
public class Stuff {
   public static final String foo = "foo";
}
```

Here is an example of calling the variable foo (while still retaining it's contents of foo):

```
public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(Stuff.foo);
    }
}
```

As mentioned, I did not have to initialize Stuff in Application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access it staticly outside of a class without initializing the class, then you make it static

Answer (score 0):

You may want a class to access that String value but you do not want to initialize the class which holds the String. This is useful if one class is using the String but not using the rest of the class that holds the String.